# laravel spatie syncpermission not working

Tags: php, laravel

i had a problem with syncPermission to role on laravel when storing data to database,the error looks like this
"Call to undefined method Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::syncPermission()", when i use this method on seeders its work properly. maybe im missing something important. so i need your help to figure it out. thankyou in advance

so this is my controller code

```
    public function store(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'name' => 'required|unique:roles,name',
        'permission' => 'required|min:1'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
    }

    $role = Role::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'guard_name' => 'api'
            
    ]);
    $role->syncPermission($request->permission);

    if($role) {
        //return success with Api Resource
        return new RoleResource(true, 'Succes', $role);
    }

    //return failed with Api Resource
    return new RoleResource(false, 'Failed', null);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be like:

```
$role->syncPermissions($request->permission);
```

Not

```
$role->syncPermission($request->permission);
```

Just use : syncPermissions (you missed 's')

Answer (score 1):

Just Use this

```
$permissions = [];
$post_permissions = $request->input('permission');
foreach ($post_permissions as $key => $val) {
    $permissions[intval($val)] = intval($val);
}
$role->syncPermissions($permissions);
```